# Manipulate text Files with bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Create an ex2 script that using the ./it/colaboradores/users.txt file will create a "XXX" file for each employee in the ./it/colaboradores/LDAP/ folder, with "XXX" as its initial. Within each file it should contain the following text:

First line example:

```
$ cat TES
Nome: TesteTeste
Email: teste.teste@xxx.pt
Numero de telemovel: 934318232
Skype: teste.cvs
```

This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/users.txt"
out="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/teste.txt"

while read line; do

        Acr="$(awk -F ';' '{print $1}' <<<"$line")"
        Nome="$(awk -F ';' '{print $2}' <<<"$line")"
        Email="$(awk -F ';' '{print $3}' <<<"$line")"
        Numero="$(awk -F ';' '{print $4}' <<<"$line")"
        Skype="$(awk -F ';' '{print $5}' <<<"$line")"

        cat  <<-!>> "$out"

       -------------------------------------------

        Acr: $Acr
        Nome: $Nome
        Email: $Email
        Numero: $Nr
        Skype: $Skype
        !

done < $input
```

In my code i test if i can manipulate , and my output for this code are :

```
-------------------------------------------

#Acr: TES
Nome: TesteTeste
Email: teste.teste@xxx.pt
Numero de telemovel: 934318232
Skype: teste.cvs

       -------------------------------------------

#Acr: XXX
Nome: PauloTeste
Email: paulo.teste@teste.pt
NR: 323322323
Skype: paulo.teste

       -------------------------------------------
```

And my dificult it's to generate one file for each person.. and when i start my script i put example:

```
./ex02 
cat TES
```

the output is:

```
Nome: TesteTeste
Email: teste.teste@xxx.pt
Numero de telemovel: 934318232
Skype: teste.cvs
```

but in one file with the file name are the firts 3 letter.txt. (e TES.txt/XXA.txt)

i know it's with maybe a cicle for.. but i dont know really how to procede.

my original txt it's something like that:

```
XXA;Teste;Teste.silva@Teste.pt;32323232;Teste.cs
XXB;Example;tes.te@Teste.pt;323232323;Teste.alx
XXC;Example;teste.te@Teste.pt;2323232;Teste.me2
XXD;ExamplesXamples;Joao.teste@Teste.pt;3232323;Teste
XXE;ExamplesXam;Pedro.teste@Teste.pt;32323232;Teste.rodrigues
```

what i want to do with the script is create a file for each person like that

file tes.txt

```
#Acr: TES
Nome: TesteTeste
Email: teste.teste@xxx.pt
Numero de telemovel: 934318232
Skype: teste.cvs



file xxx.txt 

#Acr: XXX
Nome: PauloTeste
Email: paulo.teste@teste.pt
NR: 323322323
Skype: paulo.teste
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: And i put my code, but i can't separate my code for files, thats my problem

Comment: Put some text in between. I'll tried to some edit your post and separated code from the input file, please check it and edit. A clear and nicely written post will get you more helpful answers ; ) `"$(awk -F ';' '{print $1}' <<<"$line")"` just `while IFS=';' read -r Acr Nome Email Numero Skype;`... `#Acr: XXX` - where does the hash come from? You posted many examples - what output do you _want_ to have? Could it be your input file has dos line endings?

Comment: Please don't post multiple lines in comments - they are bad for that. Click the `edit` below your question and post it in your question instead. So don't write to `>> "$out"` but instead write to separate files, like `>>"$name"`. The [bashfaq how to read a file field by field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is a good resource to learn from.

Comment: I put in the final what is the output that i want.., in the other words, in my code i have all persons in 1 file , i want to put each person in each file that person

Comment: could u help me when i have to change my code ?
in comments its dificult to see @KamilCuk

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
input="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/users.txt"
out="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/"

while IFS=';' read -r Act Nome Email Numero Skype; do
     cat  << EOF >> "$out"/"$Nome".txt
Acr: $Acr
Nome: $Nome
Email: $Email
Numero: $Numero
Skype: $Skype
EOF
done < "$input"
```

Comment: just one doubt, if i want to pass 2 parametrs in the begin like that ./ex02 cat avs 
and the script only create one file and not the all files ?

Comment: The script as shown ignores any parameters. It doesn't reference any `$1` not `$2`.

Comment: yes i know, but if i want to acept 2 args to only creat a file once, where can i put it in the code? i'm looking and try with cicle for but still not working, idk